# JS, Add a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this:

```
var f = function(){
    var args = arguments;
    args.push(this._caller);
    this._base(args);
};

f._caller = someObject;
f._base = function(x,y,z){ alert(x+':'+y+':'+z);};

f(y,z);
```

Basically - I want to give function some inner parameters, but still function should be called with its parameters and user should not know about this parameters when he calls this function.

Problem is, that in the function body 'this' will mean 'Window' and not the function in need.

So how can I do this? And can I do this at all?

Comment: [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Also note that `arguments` is not a real array, you can't `push` into it.

Comment: it's not an original example that I had 'working' - it was larger, so I made such change. Thanks for info, will know

Comment: also, function.apply won't help, because you still need to pass those parameter, or user should clearly write f.apply(f,...), while I just want f(...). Updated code to clearly show what I need

Comment: @DCoder: You can `[].push.call(arguments, f._caller)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `this` won't be the `function` itself, but the context the function was called with. You can access properties of the `function` if you name it (`var f` does not set the `name`).

   ```
   var f = function fn() {
       var _caller = fn._caller;
       var _base = fn._base;
       // ...
   };
   ```
2. The method `arguments.push()` doesn't exist as `arguments` isn't actually an `Array`. Though, you can create an `Array` from it with [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

   ```
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(argument, 0);
   args.push(_caller);
   ```
3. To set the context (`this`) and pass an `Array` of arguments, use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

   ```
   return _base.apply(this, args);
   ```

Comment: so there is no other way except for function#apply?

Comment: @AndrewYukhymchak Either that or [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) if you want to specify the value of `this`. But `.call()` would pass the `Array` as the value of a single argument.

Comment: dang... not the answer I wish to hear. TY. Closed